# Lightning *Web* Components!? Another Lightning thing?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to begin a discussion about what to do with tags around lightning components now that LWC has been [launched](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/242469/what-are-lightning-web-components).

If you've read the blog [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/12/introducing-lightning-web-components.html), you'll see that the original Aura-based components will live side-by-side with LWC components going forward.

To inform the community here, our docs will refer to the "old" style of Lightning Component as the "aura-based" programming model. The new stuff is "Lightning Web Components".

I've introduced a "lightning-web-components" tag (and seeded it with an initial tag wiki). I also have added an "lwc" tag that I intend to make a synonym for the longer tag.

As such, going forward I'm curious what folks think about how to distinguish the existing "lightning-components" tag from the new "lightning-web-components" tag.

And just to clarify a little...officially, the framework encapsulates *both* programming models as of today. In other words

```
Lightning Component Framework
|
+- Programming Model 1: Aura
|
+- Programming Model 2: LWC
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

This is a bad idea. In order to introduce [lightning-web-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-web-components), you now have a situation where people have to choose between [lightning-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-components) and the new one. You can't just alias it to [aura-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aura-components), because it'll still be abused. This has already happened with [lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning)/[lightning-experience](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-experience)/[lightning-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-components), and now you're adding 1-4 more tags that will only serve to further degrade the use of tagging Lightning questions.

If you want to do this, we **need** to burninate [lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning) and [lightning-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-components), block both of them, and then, instead of calling it [aura-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aura-components), which new users won't inherently find, name it consistently with the new tag: [lightning-aura-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-aura-components). This will make it easier for new users to find and understand the difference between the two tags. Or, alternatively, just keep on with the problem we already have.

I'm willing to help with a burnination or two, but I'm not excited about editing 9,000+ questions just to fix this problem that adding a new tag will introduce. Some community assistance would be nice. We need to nip this in the bud, and find a solution before the next release (LWC requires 45.0, thankfully, so most people won't be using it yet).

Comment: Do you think its a bad idea to have the lightning-web-component tag at all? I would have thought the distinction would have been useful. The problems one encounters with one will be distinct from the other.

Comment: @pchittum Yes, we need two separate tags. But we also need to clean up/destroy two existing tags to do so, or they will be misused. lightning-components will start to see the same problem as lightning has now. It's not that having two tags is a bad idea, it's the amount of effort we'll have to put in to cleaning up the tags to make the idea useful. These new tags require editing 9,000+ questions to re-align them with the new tags, or the old tags will continue to get used (incorrectly) until we fix the problem, or it'll cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: I totally see your point on the cleanup and the effort and agree. It wasn't clear to me if you were saying "stop the presses" altogether, though.

Comment: If you want to burninate at that scale, we should reach out to the CM team.

Comment: @AdrianLarson If there's an easier way, I'm all for it. As far as I can tell, though, lightning may refer to either lightning-components or lightning-experience. But for lightning-components, if we can simply *rename* it to `lightning-aura-components`, preferably before Monday, that would leave just one burnination of about 3,000 questions.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Not sure if you saw my previous comment, but looks like mods can rename a tag? Can you rename [tag:lightning-components] to [tag:lightning-aura-components]? There's about 1600 questions that need review for a burnination of [tag:lightning].

Answer (score 7):

Based off the blog post:

> With the addition of Lightning Web Components, there are now two ways to build Lightning components:
>
> Aura Components, leveraging its own component model, templates, and modular development programming model.
>
> Lightning Web Components, built on top of the web standards breakthroughs of the last five years: web components, custom elements, Shadow DOM, etc.

the rename should be:

- `aura-components` for questions referring to the 2014 - now lighting components
- `lightning-web-components` for future questions referring to the new web components

A similar and relevant tag migration happened on Stack Overflow around the time Angular2 was released:

> The Angular team is now referring to Angular 1.x as "Angular.js" and Angular 2.x and above is now being referred to as just "Angular." We need to make this change to the tags as well as the Documentation Titles.

and then became just Angular:

> Since new version of AngularJS framework is officially referred to as only Angular, I think all of the existing angular2-* tags should be renamed or merged to existing angular-* tags

**References**

- [Meta Stack Overflow: angular angular2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=angular+angular2)
- [Please merge [angular] into [angularjs] - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132980/please-merge-angular-into-angularjs)

Comment: The problem with aura-components is that most new users are unlikely to find the correct tag and keep using either lightning-components or might even start using lightning-web-components incorrectly. I've seen this happen already, so we need to come up with a solution quick before this happens again.

Comment: I think we would have to use lightning-aura-components as newbies will not think of them as aura-compoents and even if you are experienced people are used to calling them lighting-components.